# Iniciar sesión en una pagina web por medio de código

Tags: python, scraping

tengo una consulta ¿Cómo iniciar sesión a una pagina web por medio de código? la pregunta no va dirigida a crear un formulario en html si no a como rellenar automáticamente la parte de **USUARIO** y **CONTRASEÑA** dentro de una pagina web (esto es para poder hacer *scraping*).

Bueno ahora que esta el contexto me gustaría que fuera en Python o JavaScript (ya que manejo un poco mas esos lenguajes).
Para Python tengo este código:

```py
# libreria para el scraping (no utilizada en el codigo)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
from lxml import html

User = "UsuarioValido"
Pass = "ContraseñaValida"
url = "https://urlDelScraping.com"
LOGIN_URL = "https://URLIniciarSesion.com"


# 2 Get login 
session_requests = requests.session()
result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)

# 3 Create payload
payload = {
    "Usuario": User, 
    "clave": Pass, 
    "btn-login": "Ingresar" 
}

# 4 Perform login
session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

# 5 Scrape url
result = session_requests.get(url, headers = dict(referer = url))
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
print(html.tostring(tree))
```

Soy nuevo en esto del scraping y me tope con el error de la pagina que quiero obtener los datos se necesita iniciar sesión Los códigos que están arriba son de internet, por algún motivo los códigos de arriba no me dejan por ejemplo en el de python me dice "sesión invalida" (con el código html de la pagina de iniciar sesión algo como `<title> .... <\title> ... <h2> sesion invalida <\h2> ...`).

Actualizacion:

He creado un Pastebin donde la url es: https://pastebin.com/uLnNP9L8

y la contraseña es: eH1ZLE6tAp

Para que puedan hacer pruebas.

Espero haberme explicado bien de lo que va el post, Saludos.

Comment: Por favor has tu pregunta más específica, solo debes de especificar el problema que tienes en un lenguaje, lee [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Python tiene el módulo `selenium` que sirve para hacer scarpping y tiene más funcionalidades que beautifullsoup

Comment: @Christian Hola lo hice lo mas general hablo de 2 lenguajes pero especifico uno mas sobre el otro que es Python, la pregunta es una solamente, tendré en cuenta seleccionar un solo idioma para la próxima, gracias.

Comment: @Christian hola Sabrías solucionar el problema de ingresar a una pagina web por medio de la librería `selenium`

Comment: Los consejos que te doy es para que tu pregunta actual no termine cerrada y obtengas ayuda. Algo que creo que muchos necesitarán para elaborar una respuesta es la página a la que quieres scrapear para así poder hacer pruebas, sería bueno que la agregaras

Comment: @Christian Editare la pagina muchas gracias

Comment: En el caso de un login no es necesario ninguna librería de scraping, puedes hacer el GET/POST con las credenciales, guardas la sesión, token o lo que sea que devuelva y continuas con las herramientas de scraping usando esa sesión/token que obtuviste.

Comment: Hola @Emeeus soy nuevo en esto, tienes algún link de ejemplo sobre los GET/POST o si no es molestia generar un ejemplo

Comment: En el ejemplo de python pareciera que ya lo estás haciendo, sería `requests.get`, en JavaScript veo que intentas hacerlo desde al lado del cliente, no va a poder ser posible, a menos que la página que intentas scrapear te deje hacer ajax hacia ella, caso contrario, la única opción con JavaScript es usando node, y una librería conocida para scrapping es pupeteer.

Comment: Todo el código va aquí, no en enlaces externos. ¿que pasará cuando el enlace ya no esté disponible? En el futuro otros no podrán aprender, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)